# Electron: print iframe given reference to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing, electron

I would like to use the [`react-to-print`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print) library to print an `iframe` from my Electron app. How can I use the `iframe` reference to get the correct window/element to print?

```
const handleElectronPrint = async (target: HTMLIFrameElement) {
  // Instead of this (printing the whole page)
  // let win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();

  // How do I print just the referenced iframe?
  // `target` iframe has id="printWindow", how to select it?
  let win = BrowserWindow.getMyIframe();
  
  // Is this the right way to do the print once we have the iframe?
  const options = { printBackground: true };
  win.webContents.print(options, (success, failureReason) => {
    if (!success) console.log(failureReason);
  
    console.log('Print Initiated');
  }); 
};

<ReactToPrint
 ...
 print={handleElectronPrint}
/>
```

Comment: Try creating a BrowserWindow, and assign the iframe to it temporarily. then print and delete the browserwindow?

Comment: @Base64__ I have no knowledge of Electron, why I'm asking the question heh. If you could provide an working example, possibly as an answer, that would be appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert the iframe object to [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). And load the URL in a new hidden BrowserWindow object.

Build data URL in [Renderer process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model) and send the URL to Main process using [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation). In main process do the BrowserWindow.loadURL and printing.

**App.js**

```js
  // Send print request to the Main process
  this.handlePrint = function (target) {
   return new Promise(() => {
    console.log('forwarding print request to the main process...');

    // convert the iframe into data url
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs
    let data = target.contentWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    //console.log(data);
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/html' });
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    window.electronAPI.printComponent(url, (response) => {
     console.log('Main: ', response);
    });
   });
  };
```

**main.js**

```js
// List of all options at -
// https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsprintoptions-callback
const printOptions = {
 silent: false,
 printBackground: true,
 color: true,
 margin: {
  marginType: 'printableArea',
 },
 landscape: false,
 pagesPerSheet: 1,
 collate: false,
 copies: 1,
 header: 'Page header',
 footer: 'Page footer',
};

ipcMain.handle('printComponent', (event, url) => {
 let win = new BrowserWindow({ show: false });
 win.loadURL(url);

 win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
  win.webContents.print(printOptions, (success, failureReason) => {
   console.log('Print Initiated in Main...');
   if (!success) console.log(failureReason);
  });
 });
 return 'done in main';
});
```

**preload.js**

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
 printComponent: async (url, callback) => {
  let response = await ipcRenderer.invoke('printComponent', url);
  callback(response);
 },
});
```

Here is the list of all [print options](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsprintoptions-callback). Some options like page size, margins, orientation can be set in CSS @page rule refer App.css in my demo app.

Here is demo app on GitHub [electron-react-to-print-demo](https://github.com/OnkarRuikar/electron-react-to-print-demo).

---

**Print Preview:** There is no, Chrome browser style, inbuilt print preview feature due to [these reasons](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4890#issuecomment-203727837). We need to implement our own workaround. Like print to PDF and show pdf in new window:
[image]

```js
//handle preview
ipcMain.handle('previewComponent', (event, url) => {
 let win = new BrowserWindow({ title: 'Preview', show: false, autoHideMenuBar: true });

 win.loadURL(url);

 win.webContents.once('did-finish-load', () => {
  win.webContents.printToPDF(printOptions).then((data) => {
    let buf = Buffer.from(data);
    var data = buf.toString('base64');
    let url = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data;

    win.webContents.on('ready-to-show', () => {
     win.show();
     win.setTitle('Preview');
    });
    win.webContents.on('closed', () => win = null;);
    win.loadURL(url);

   })
   .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
   });
 });
 return 'shown preview window';
});
```

I've added above preview feature in [electron-react-to-print-demo](https://github.com/OnkarRuikar/electron-react-to-print-demo).

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic, and _exactly_ what I was looking for, thank you! One quick follow-up: is there a way to get Electron to show a preview of the print similar to what a browser does?

Comment: Unfortunately they haven't used the print APIs from chromium. All are suggesting same workaround of showing printed pdf in a new window as I've discussed in the updated answer.